# bathtub leak into walls

Tags: plumbing, leak, bathtub

We discovered a bath tub leak from our second floor bathroom which dripped through the sidings. The bathroom has the original fixtures from 1989. It leaks when there's excess amount of water used.
Would this be a simple problem of refinishing everything using plumber's putty?

Comment: What do you mean by "excess amount of water"?

Comment: Do you know what part of the plumbing is leaking? Is it behind the wall is it the pipes or is it the cartridge itself?

Answer (score 1):

Plumbers putty is for specific purpose and may or may not solve the problem. You **must** find the root cause of the issue. You need to investigate and troubleshoot. it could be leaky faucet components, leaky tub shoe, leaky overflow pipe, leaky trim, etc. Remove all the faucet trim and run water, look in the wall with a flashlight. You made need to open the wall from behind or the ceiling from below. This very well be much more complicated than jamming putty everywhere.

If you do not understand the above and/or don't want to do some serious work... call a plumber.